# Live-server Visual Studio Code browser won't auto update

Tags: browser, visual-studio-code, visual-web-developer, npm-live-server

I'm pretty new to web developing and very new to VS code. I'm trying to use live-server to be able to get the html in the browser to update without having to refresh the browser. I can't get it to work and I have been googling and trying stuff out for 2 days. Can somebody help me while I still have some hairs left on my head?

Thank you!
/Joel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's necessary to firsly save the file in which you are working(`html`file).
In my case i go to `file` and select `autosave`. it starts to work as wish.